# SD card not getting accessed in android

Tags: java, android, sd-card, android-sdcard

I am facing continuous problem with accessing SD Card even after using `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` or even directly using `/sdcard/` application is fetching data from phone's internal memory .I am using moto e for testing

Please help

```
public class SongsManager {

final String MEDIA_PATH = new String(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath());
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

// Constructor
public SongsManager(){

}




public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getPlayList(){
    File home = new File(MEDIA_PATH);
    walkdir(home);





    return songsList;



}

public void walkdir(File dir) {
    String Pattern = ".mp3";
    File listFile[] = dir.listFiles();
    if (listFile != null) {
    for (int i = 0; i < listFile.length; i++) {
    if (listFile[i].isDirectory()) {
    walkdir(listFile[i]);
    } else {
    if (listFile[i].getName().endsWith(Pattern)){
        for (File file : dir.listFiles(new FileExtensionFilter())) {
            HashMap<String, String> song = new HashMap<String, String>();
            song.put("songTitle", file.getName().substring(0, (file.getName().length() - 4)));
            song.put("songPath", file.getPath());

            // Adding each song to SongList
            songsList.add(song);
        }

    }
    }
    }  
    }  
    }

}


class FileExtensionFilter implements FilenameFilter {
    public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
        return (name.endsWith(".mp3") || name.endsWith(".MP3"));
    }
}
```

Comment: https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/09/storage-situation-removable-storage.html

Comment: after using getAbsolutePath() it is giving the path /storage/emulated/0.Still not accessing SD Card .

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing this:

```
final String MEDIA_PATH = new String(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath());
...
File home = new File(MEDIA_PATH);
```

You could just do this:

```
File home = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
```

and then to call you method `walkdir`

```
walkdir(home);
```

I think that the problem is in the `getPath()` method. Maybe it should be the `getAbsolutePath()` method

Comment: after using getAbsolutePath() it is giving the path /storage/emulated/0.Still not accessing SD Card

Comment: Do it with the expression I gave you `File home = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();`. The `getAbsolutePath()` method was as a second way

Answer (score 0):

That is normal for Android. It's not easy to get the path to removable media on android. You can read a lot about this on this site. Add a directory picker to your app so the user canindicate it. Try getExternalFileDirs(). If it gives you two directories the latter will be the micro SD card.

Comment: please can you give a example according to the code provided .

Comment: If you fiddle around a little bit with that function the IDE will give enough hints to implement some code lines. If not you can later show your code.